# Split Jenkins job into smaller jobs from config file

Tags: jenkins

I have a directory full of unit tests and an internal testing framework that can both run all the tests or run any individual test. I currently have one Jenkins job that runs all the tests. This does not provide the granularity of seeing the status, and history of statuses, for each individual tests, only the aggregate.

Is there a way in Jenkins, perhaps with a plugin, to create **a single job and within that job have smaller child jobs that each individually run one test**? Moreover, since the test suite is regularly changing, is there a way to **create the child jobs from a config file** that lists all the tests, rather than manually doing it for every test that is added or removed?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) that adds a [Domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (DSL) that infor runing jobs in parallel:

```
parallel (
    // job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("job1") },
    { build("job2") },
    { build("job3") }
)
// job4 will be triggered after jobs 1, 2 and 3 complete
build("job4")
```

Copied from the above website

There is also the [Parallel Test Executor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parallel+Test+Executor+Plugin)  but you don't say if your tests are compatiable with JUnit

Comment: Thanks @GrahamA-- I will try this out and report back on how it performs.

Comment: I am leaning more towards something like [Jenkins Job Builder](http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/index.html#) which uses a YAML file to produce Jenkins job configurations. I guess the difference is it lets me define the jobs programmatically, even if it may not allow the jobs to be hierarchical (though I'm still looking into this).